# How can I generate random numbers for demo charts that roughly trend up and to the right?

Tags: javascript, json, math, random

I need to generate random numbers for several charts that go up and to the right.

I'm using a JavaScript charting engine so will ultimately require numbers in JSON, but I can handle the conversion if you have an easy way outside of JavaScript.

Here's a simple randomNumber generator in JavaScript:

```
function randomNumber(minimum, maximum){
    return Math.round( Math.random() * (maximum - minimum) + minimum);
}
console.log(randomNumber(0,100));
```

The above would work if `min` and `max` grew over time. Can you point me in the right direction?

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ox4wjrf/) to try out various solutions, including a handy chart: http://jsfiddle.net/9ox4wjrf/

Here's a rough example of the sorts of charts I need to build with generated data:

[image: rough example of desired results]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this may work:

```
var a = 0.05;
var b = 10; //play with these values to your liking
var y;

//loop here from 0 to whatever
y = a * x^2 + b * x * Math.random();
//or using your randomMumber function:
y = a * x^2 + randomMumber(- b * x / 2, b * x / 2);
```

This way the noise gets bigger when further to the right

Comment: Lovely. Works like a charm. Can you help the `y-min` to grow over `x` as well? (slower than the `y-max`)

Comment: What is `y-min`? I have updated slightly my answer, so maybe it answers your question already?

Comment: I mean the minimum possible value for y remains 0, even as x grows. You are correct that more noise should be expected as x grows. But the noise should still trend up and to the right. I just linked to a jsfiddle in the question. I'll post here when I have your solution in the fiddle.

Comment: I have updated the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9ox4wjrf/2/ Try to play with `c` and `d` - When `c` is bigger then the curve goes up faster

Comment: I like it. Can you suggest a way to keep y>0 at all times? Hopefully in a way that doesn't turn all negative values into 0.

Comment: `y = Math.abs(y)` may do the trick since it's all random anyway

Comment: Well done. These settings consistently generated desired results: http://jsfiddle.net/9ox4wjrf/3/

Answer (score 2):

Define your trend without noise, as an array of growing numbers. Call that X and copy it into another array Y. Then for each point in Y add a number generated by the built-in random number generator in Math. This will add the illusion of noise.

If you want more random options, checkout random-js on GitHub. https://github.com/mobiusklein/random-js. It is a great library but forks are helping smooth the rough edges. Also, https://github.com/tmcw/simple-statistics for linear regression lines.

Answer (score 2):

This will be pseudocode, but you could do something like this:

```
int randomRangePotential = 20; // percentage of random growth/shrinkage
int likelyhoodOfGrowth = 95; // likelyhood of datapoint being more than the previous
int numberOfDataPoints = 100; // number of data points to generate

int lastDataPointValue = 50;

for (int iterator = 0; iterator < numberOfDataPoints; iterator++)
{
    // generate random number to determine positive or negative growth 0 - 100
    // generate randomRange, a random number between 1 and randomRangePotential
    // if random number > likelyhoodOfGrowth

       // generate random number for datapoint that is (lastDataPoint = lastDataPoint * 1.randomRange)
       // add the random number to a datapoint

    // if random number < likelyhoodOfGrowth

       // generate random number for datapoint that is (lastDataPoint = lastDataPoint * -1.randomRange)
       // add the random number to a datapoint

    // lastDataPointValue = thisdatapoint

}
```